# INOUT Parameter Mysql Procedure(not IN OUT)

Tags: mysql

I have a stored proc which has been designed as

```
OUT       id
INOUT     name
IN        password
OUT       activate
```

I want to retrieve the values id, name, active.

When I do

```
CALL login(@id,'abc','abc',@activate);
select @id as rm_out_param, @activate as active_out_param,@name as uname;
```

it shows me an error

```
OUT or INOUT argument 2 is not a variable
```

When I try to use

```
CALL login(@id,@name,'abc','abc',@activate);
select @id as rm_out_param, @activate as active_out_param,@name as uname;
```

it shows me error

```
Invalid arguments supplied expected 4,5 given
```

How to overcome this to get the resultant output as  id, name, active

Thanks and much appreciated

Comment: try this: `SET @name := 'abc';CALL login(@id,@name,'abc',@activate);...`

Comment: @1000111 Thanks so much...That helped. Please 'POST YOUR ANSWER', so that I can mark it as correct. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a stored proc which has been designed as
>
> ```
> OUT       id
> INOUT     name
> IN        password
> OUT       activate
> ```

Since three of the above arguments are `OUT` type. So, you must pass variables in place of them not any value or string literal.

So, here how you should call the procedure:

```
SET @name := 'abc';

CALL login(@id,@name,'abc',@activate);

select @id as rm_out_param, @activate as active_out_param,@name as uname;
```